How to prevent useMutation isPending from removing component and replacing it with the spinner component
In react query it gives you the isPending feature which allows you to create some type of spinner when an operation occurs. However, when you use the isPending feature, the component that triggers the mutation gets replaced by the returned spinner that is inside isPending block but I don't want the spinner to replace the component instead I want the spinner to be placed on top of the component. I am not sure how to do this?
function NewUser() {
  const { isPending, mutate } = useMutation(createUser);

  if (isPending) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <span>{`An error has occurred: ${error.message}`}</span>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isSuccess && <span>User added successfully</span>}

      <button onClick={() => mutate({ name: 'Gapur', lastName: 'Kassym' })}>
        Create User
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


As you can see in the image below the card gets replaced by the spinner pop up modal. I still want my card to appear but with the spinner on top of the card.
This image is the card.
When I click on the button that triggers the mutation the card disappears and gets replaced by the spinner. I don't want the card to be replaced, instead I want the spinner to be on top of the card while it is in isPending state.

Using the return statement inside a component will define what to (exclusively) render.
Currently you are returning the loader, but instead you may want to include your isPending condition inside the normal template you are returning for your card like below
function NewUser() {
  const { isPending, mutate } = useMutation(createUser);

  if (error) {
    return <span>{`An error has occurred: ${error.message}`}</span>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isPending && <span class="loader">Loading...</span>}
      {isSuccess && <span>User added successfully</span>}

      <button onClick={() => mutate({ name: 'Gapur', lastName: 'Kassym' })}>
        Create User
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

Then you just have to decide what CSS style to set to the loader so it's on top of your card (something like an absolute positioning having your div relative, centering the loader...etc) you can find a lot of useful example on google by looking at how to make a modal in CSS.
